# Displaying Different Languages in Label using html parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an URL -----> 182.72.253.75/test/surya/telugu.html 
And this url contains some information in telugu language..

Now I need help in the following aspects---->

1) **How to parse that html url**..

2) **How to display the information in that link in a UILabel in iphone simulator...**(Because the information is in **telugu language** not in **english language**) ..

**Thanks in Advance...**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have solved my problem...

Actually the URL contains...

ాష్ట్రపతి ప్రణబ్ ముఖర్జీ అధ్యక్షతన రాష్ట్రపతి భవన్లో గవర్నర్ల సదస్సు సోమవారం ప్రారంభమైంది. రెండు రోజుల పాటు జరిగే ఈ సదస్సులో 30 మంది గవర్నర్లు, లెప్ట్నెంట్‌ గవర్నర్లు పాల్గొన్నారు. ప్రధాని మన్మోహన్‌సింగ్‌తోపాటుగా, రక్షణ, ఆర్థిక, వ్యవసాయం, హోం, మానవ వనరుల అభివృద్ధి, పట్టణాభివృద్ధి, జలవనరులశాఖల మంత్రులతోపాటుగా, పౌరసర ఫరాలు, ఆహార, ప్రజాపంపిణీ, తాగునీరు, పారిశుద్ధ్య శాఖల స్వతంత్ర మంత్రులు హాజరయ్యారు. రాష్ట్రాల ఆర్థికాభివృద్ధితో పాటు మహిళల భద్రతపై ఈ సదస్సులో చర్చించనున్నారు.

The background source code of this This HTML page is as follows...

http://ashokios.blogspot.in/2013/02/background-sourcetemporary-post.html

But this is not in correct formate

so..,

1)Need to get the correct formate..

2)Need to convert into Dictionary.

Here we need two custom classes

XMLReader and GDataXMLDocument..

Now the solution is...

```
NSString *serverResponseStr=[XMLReader getResponseForService:@"http://182.72.253.75/test/surya/telugu.html" withParametersString:nil];

NSString *validXMLstring=[[NSString alloc]init];




GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithHTMLString:serverResponseStr error:nil];
if (doc)
{
    validXMLstring=[[doc rootElement] XMLString];
}


NSDictionary *responseDictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
responseDictionary=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:validXMLstring error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",responseDictionary);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[[[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"html"]objectForKey:@"body"]objectForKey:@"table"]objectForKey:@"tr"]objectForKey:@"td"]objectForKey:@"text"]);


self.myTextView.text=[[[[[[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"html"]objectForKey:@"body"]objectForKey:@"table"]objectForKey:@"tr"]objectForKey:@"td"]objectForKey:@"text"];
```